# DateTime.ParseExact throws FormatException for sv-SE culture when time is in the afternoon

Tags: c#, datetime, localization

I am observing some strange behavior in case of `DateTime.ParseExact` method with the Swedish (`sv-SE`) culture.

My computer's culture is `en-US` but the business logic demands the `sv-SE` culture. So I set it on the current thread first.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
```

Then I do the following to parse the `DateTime` value. The datetime I am trying to parse here is **11:57 AM on 27th May 2012**.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("270512T11:57", "ddMMyyThh:mm", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```

This works just fine.

But I get the exception when the time is from the night. When I try to parse the datetime stamp of value **11:57 PM on 27th May 2012**.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("270512T23:57", "ddMMyyThh:mm", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```

The above line gives the `FormatException` with the message **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**.

What is really wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried replacing 'hh' by 'HH'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hh is 12-hour clock only.  If you change your format string to "ddMMyyTHH:mm" it should work.